# NopCommerce - Page Navigation Issue with Telerik-Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce. I have used telerik-grid to bind data in a table and data binded successfully. I have create method named "EditContact" for Edit operation. but when i clicked Edit link to redirect page named "_CreateOrUpdateContact.cshtml", i got "Page not found" page.

**telerik-grid code :**

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<AddressModel>()
                .Name("vendors-grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(x => x.CountryName)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.FirstName)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.LastName)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Title)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Email)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                        .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Address1)
                    .Width(200).Centered();
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                        .Width(200)
                        .Centered()
                        .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "Edit", new { id = x.Id }))
                        .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"EditContact/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
                        .Title(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text);
                    columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                    .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text, "Delete", new { id = x.Id }))
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Delete/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text + "</a>")
                    .Centered().Width(200)
                    .HeaderTemplate(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text);
                })
                .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ListContacts", "VendorDetails",new { vendorId = Model.Id }))
                .EnableCustomBinding(true))
```

**EditContact.cshtml Code:**

```
@model AddressModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="section-header">
   <div class="options">
        <input type="submit" name="save" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Save")" />
        <input type="submit" name="save-continue" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.SaveContinue")" />
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("_CreateOrUpdateContact", Model)
}
@Html.DeleteConfirmation("vendor-delete")
```

**VendorDetailsController Methods:**

```
[HttpPost, GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult ListContacts(int vendorId,GridCommand command)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageVendors))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        var Addresses = _addressService.GetVendorAddresses(vendorId);

        var gridModel = new GridModel<AddressModel>
        {
            Data = Addresses.Select(x =>
            {
                var a = new AddressModel();
                PrepareAddressModel(a, x, false);
                return a;
            }),
            Total = Addresses.Count,
        };
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = gridModel
        };
    }  

    // edit vendor contact
    public ActionResult EditContact(int id)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageVendors))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        var address = _addressService.GetAddressById(id);
        int vendorId = _vendorContactService.GetVendorIdByAddressId(address.Id);

        if (address == null)
            //No Address found
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = vendorId });

        var model = new AddressModel();
        model.VendorId = vendorId;

        //Ordering Method
        model.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "-- Select --", Value = "0" });
        foreach (var c in _countryService.GetAllCountries(true))
            model.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() });

        PrepareAddressModel(model, address, false);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong?
How can i redirect from telerik grid- Edit Link to _CreateOrUpdateContact.cshtml page?

Comment: Please post your EditContact action

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if "_CreateOrUpdateContact.cshtml" is in the same location with "EditContact.cshtml". I will suggest you to debug the code. Put a breakpoint at  "public ActionResult EditContact(int id)" then check if debug point is hit after clicking the edit link from grid. If it is not hit then there may be some problem in route.

It would be better if you can provide the screen shot of the error you found

Answer (score 0):

you can check the route here in the telerik-grid

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
       .Width(200)
       .Centered()
       .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "Edit", new { id = x.Id }))
       .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"EditContact/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
       .Title(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text);
```

as I think the route had a problem I should be like that

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
       .Width(200)
       .Centered()
       .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "EditContact", new { id = x.Id }))
       .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"EditContact/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
       .Title(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text);
```